# Microphone noise cancellation in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, updates, microphone, helpfile

I have tried almost every solution available on the Internet regarding microphone noise cancellation, but none of the solutions works for me. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What sort of microphone are you using? Sometimes noise cancellation is impossible with the wrong sort of hardware …

Comment: boat bassheads 100...It's working fine with a smartphone but not with Ubuntu 20.04